# Minimum and Maximum Eigenvalue of self-adjoint matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking through Lax's linear algebra, and I'm trying to understand the following.  In his book it is written that, assuming $X$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $H$, we can write
$$\frac{(x,Hx)}{(x,x)}=\frac{\sum a_iz_i^2}{\sum z_i^2}$$
where $z_i$ is the coefficient corresponding to the $i$th eigenvector in expanding $x$ on the basis of eienvectors, and $a_i$ is the amount this is changed by $H$, i.e.
$$Hx=\sum z_ia_i f_i$$
where $f_i$ is the $i$th eigenvector of $H$.  He then arranges $a_i$ in increasing order
$$a_1\le a_2\le\cdots\le a_n$$
which he then writes that choosing $z_1\ne0$ and the other $z_i=0$, we get
$$a_1=\min\limits_{s\ne0}\frac{(x,Hx)}{(x,x)}$$
which I think is the **first typo**, where $s\ne0$ should be $x\ne0$, since $s$ is not defined as anything.

He then writes that similarly
$$a_n=\min\limits_{x\ne0}\frac{(x,Hx)}{(x,x)}$$
which I think is the **second typo**, as it should be $\max$ instead of $\min$.  He writes that the minimum and maximum, respectively, are taken on at points $x=f$ that are eigenvectors of $H$ with eigenvalues $a_1$ and $a_n$ respectively.

Are these two genuine typos or have I missed something?